# Escape comment syntax in strings with listings

Tags: listings, literate-programming

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  morecomment=[s]{<<}{>>},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def expand():
    """<<expand documentation>>"""
    for hook in noweb:
        <<expand noweb hook>>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

How can I get *both* occurrences of the syntax to be styled as the latter?

[image: output]

---

Edit for the wonderful Jubobs: (a *less* minimal working example :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  moredelim=*[s][\lst@stringstyle]{"""}{"""},
  moredelim=[s][\lst@commentstyle]{<<}{>>},
}
\renewcommand*\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]"

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def expand():
    """foo <<expand documentation>>"""
    for hook in noweb:
        <<expand noweb hook>>

def marked_alone(node, neighbors):
    """\forall n \in N(n), "marked"(n) = 0

    There are no marked nodes in this node's neighborhood."""

    return not any(map(lambda n: n['marked'], neighbors))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image: output 2]

Comment: So you want anything delimited by `<<` and `>>`, whether it be inside a docstring or elsewhere, to be typeset in comment style? Is that correct? What should be the style applied to docstrings (outside `<< ... >>`)?

Comment: @Jubobs You are correct; And I dunno—I didn't really think about that.  `showstringspaces` should definitely be disabled in docstrings (it would get super messy, as you can imagine), but I can't think of anything extra to add to that style.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks! And for the record, my brain is a little toasted at the moment. I've got the draft of my undergrad thesis (30 pages single-spaced) due in two hours; I've already been up for about 40 hours.  I might be a tad dramatic `;)`

Comment: I know the feeling. Good luck!

Comment: Sean, I'm tempted to vote to close this as "unclear what you're asking", unless you add further specifications.

Comment: @Jubobs my apologies; I've been on the road for the past week or so and have a draft (of sorts) on my computer at home. Just to be clear, are you asking for a formal grammar, or would simply a couple more use cases suffice?

Comment: No problem `:)` I'm just wandering what the style of the docstring (i.e. outside `<<` `>>` delimiters) should be. Perhaps a couple more use cases would be helpful, actually...

Comment: @Jubobs oh that's easy. Doc string is generally (well, *ideally*) lengthy prose, so I'm not sure it would count as a string. Possibly comment-style would be better.

Comment: In that case, why not simply use `morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""}`?

Comment: @jubobs perhaps it should be an entirely different part of the syntax? If we're talking purely from an ideal system design. Documentation has a very different air to it than a comment. \\ I just find it strange that, in the last screenshot, `in` is considered as code-style.

Comment: So to summarise, in doc strings, you want: 1) some custom style, but 2) anything within `<<` `>>` should be typeset in the same style as it would be outside a doc string, and 3) keywords should not be highlighted as such. Right?

Comment: @Jubobs correct :)

Comment: 1) and 3) is easy, but satisfying all three seems difficult...

Comment: @Jubobs It might simplify things to say that, instead of implementing what would essentially be a 'style stack' to just have the `<<…>>` syntax *always* be comment, and just switch back to code/docstring syntax depending on the context in which it was entered. (Saying it 'solo foes things' is assuming a good deal about listings' internal workings.)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. If it suits you, I'll flesh out my answer a bit more.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  moredelim=*[s][\lst@stringstyle]{"""}{"""},
  moredelim=[s][\lst@commentstyle]{<<}{>>},
  showstringspaces=false,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def expand():
    """foo <<expand documentation>>"""
    for hook in noweb:
        <<expand noweb hook>>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks fantastic to me! If you're curious, there seems to be a small issue if you set `showstringspaces=true`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DKrxB.png) (https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/590ec4d6edfeb415592a)

Comment: @SeanAllred I'll look into it. That snippet visible on your screenshot... could you add it to your question, or make it available somewhere?

Comment: See my edit above :)

Comment: @SeanAllred My approach is little more than a trick, instead of a satisfactory solution. I can't think of a way of solving the `showstringspaces` problem. Maybe in a few years, when I know the `listings` source code like the back of my hand...

Comment: @SeanAllred To be honest, a comment (typeset as such) inside a string (be it a docstring or not) doesn't really make sense to me... Perhaps you should just define `"""` to be comment delimiters (`morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""}`); that would save you some hassle.